# how to make a wplang for network fill automatically

Tags: plugins, multisite

I made a new network in my website its default language was ar when I add a new website it does not fill it WPLANG automatically, I made it manually but how to make it fill automatically.

Comment: Can you please post the exact line of code you used for WPLANG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Thanks all I found the answer

```
update_option( 'WPLANG', 'ar' );
```